# Firebase rule simulator user interface is not working

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Firebase rule simulator user interface is not working.
The run button to test added rules is not responding. Nothing is happening.. Any one else got this issue? Or is it just mine ?

Comment: Its been two days now, I tried in multiple browsers and machines too. Any help any one?

Comment: Hi, its solved automatically.. I really wonder how reliable Firebase is?